# Relative path in build/_app/immutable/start-1234.js

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Just built my app with adapter-static successfully... and got my index.html along with _app and all the associated JS.  However when viewing my SPA on the web I'm getting bunch of Not Found errors in the console - *aside: I'm deploying my site to SharePoint (corporate stuff, only option)*

I tried changing my `svelte.config.js` settings with this

```
adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: '200.html',
            base: './'
        })
```

However it seems like this only applies to `index.html` and the auto-generated JS in `build/_app/immutable/start-1234.js` ignores it.

I've tried looking at `start-1234.js` but it's pretty obfuscated and don't know what to adjust.  Solutions highly appreciated.